# Cannot read property "push" of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an error when I try to push a value in an array. The mystic thing in this error is that it only occurs on the Ionic Dev App, whereas in the Google Chrome Console, everything works perfectly.

I did initialize the array, so the error doesn't come from here. Maybe, the error comes from an asynchronous operation, but I don't see where I don't catch a promise...

```
initModelesList(){
  this.addModele = this.navParams.get('addModele') || false;
  this.deleteModele = this.navParams.get("deleteModele") || false;
  if (!!this.addModele){
    this.modelesList.push(this.addModele); //error here
    this.saveModelesList();
  }
  if (!!this.deleteModele){
    const index: number = this.modelesList.indexOf(this.deleteModele);
    if (index !== -1){
      this.modelesList.splice(index,1)
    }
    this.saveModelesList()
  }
}
saveModelesList(){
 this.storage.set('modelesList',this.modelesList)
}
getModelesList(){
  this.storage.get('modelesList').then((modelesList) => {
    this.modelesList=modelesList;
    this.initModelesList()
  },()=>{
    this.modelesList=[];
    this.initModelesList();
  })
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the error on the Ionic Dev App.

[image]

Comment: So, the typical question here: if you log `this.modelesList` before `this.modelesList.push(this.addModele);` what does it log? Is it different from `undefined` | `null`? Is it an array? Does it have a `push` function?

Comment: It logs null... But I don't know why actually. If the "modelesList" doesn't exist in my Storage, this.modeleList should initialize to [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have initialized  **`modelesList`**

You can explicitly check if it's not null and create one if needed:

```
this.modelesList= this.modelesList|| [];
```

Comment: I wouldn't have asked the question if this was the problem. A lot of people already did, my question would have been useless and redundant.